# Emacsで編集したデータを1日毎にディレクトリを分けてバックアップしたい

Tags: emacs, elisp

emacsでファイルを保存するたびにファイルをバックアップする設定を施しています。
現在init.elに定義してあるコードは以下になります。

```
;; バックアップファイルを世代管理して保存先を変更します。
(when (setq make-backup-files t)
  (setq backup-directory-alist
    (cons (cons "\\.*$" (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/backup"))
      backup-directory-alist))
  (setq version-control t)       ;; 複数のバックアップ世代を管理します。
;  (setq kept-old-versions 16)    ;; 古いものをいくつ残すか
  (setq kept-new-versions 256)   ;; 新しいものをいくつ残すか
  (setq delete-old-versions t)   ;; 確認せずに古いものを消します。
  (setq vc-make-backup-files t)) ;; バージョン管理下のファイルもバックアップを作ります。

;; 保存するたびにバックアップファイルを作成するようにします。
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s")
 '(lambda () (interactive) (save-buffer 16)))
```

これでファイルを保存する度に`~/.emacs.d/backup`にバックアップファイルが作成され、ときどき消してしまったコードなどを復活させるために何度か助けられています。

すごく便利なのですが、`~/.emacs.d/backup`のなかに大量のファイルが作成され、dirredなどでディレクトリにアクセスするとものすごく重たいです。

これを１日毎に`20150507`というようなディレクトリを作成し、そこにバックアップファイルが保存されるようにしたいのですが、`emacs lisp`にあまり詳しくないのでわかりませんでした。

投げっぱなしになっているような気もしますが、よろしければ改変したコードを教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EmacsWiki: Bakcup Directory](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupDirectory#toc3)のページにバックアップの作成例が載っています。参考にしてみてください。

私は上記のページを参考にしたコードを利用しています。

```
(defun my:make-backup-file-name (file)
  (let ((dirname (file-name-as-directory
                  (format-time-string
                   (expand-file-name "backup/%Y-%m-%d/" user-emacs-directory)))))
    (or (file-directory-p dirname)
        (make-directory dirname t))
    (expand-file-name (file-name-nondirectory file) dirname)))

(setq make-backup-file-name-function #'my:make-backup-file-name)
```

これを`.eamcs`に記述すると`~/.emacs.d/backup/2015-05-07/XXX.txt`のように日付毎にディレクトリを分けてファイルをバックアップしてくれます。

テキストファイルが大部分なので容量的にはあまり気にしないとは思いますが、バックアップされたファイルは自動では削除されないため放っておくとどんどん増えます。古いものは定期的に削除したほうが良いでしょう。

Comment: `format-time-string`を使えばよかっただけだったのですね！有難うございました！

Answer (score 1):

もう既に「議題に沿った」回答がついているのでこれは蛇足なんですけど
日別バックアップ取るくらいなら SCM (ソースコード管理ツール) で履歴管理するといいです。

git とか mercurial とか導入しましょう。一度使ったら手放せなくなります。
既に使っている上での質問ならごめんなさい。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！確かにファイル数は膨大になるのでmercurialは初耳ですが、git等のバージョン管理ツールを使うのは一般的ですよね。しかしcommitするまでは安心できないし、emacsによるファイルバックアップを設定しておけばgitの管理下に置かれていないファイルなど全て保存されるので、とりあえずemacsで編集すれば何があっても大丈夫という安心感が生まれるので設定していました。Trampを利用してサーバのテキストを直接書き変えたファイルも全てローカルに保存されるので環境ごとにいちいち設定する必要もないので更に安心です。